# When does the same-origin policy prevent a request from being sent?

Tags: same-origin-policy

I have been dealing with some confusions on the same-origin policy.

Let's say my attack looks like this. On page at `evil.com` the attacker has put (jQuery):

```
$.post('http://bank.com/transfer', { to: 'ciro', ammount: '100' })
```

The attacker then convinces you to visit `evil.com`.

Will this payload (jQuery) still execute? Would it send a request or throw an error without sending the request?

I am comparing this with `XMLHttpRequest` where the request at least goes but the response is not allowed to be read because of same-origin policy violations. In case of SOP violation, does the request always travel to the server? Are there any cases where SOP prevents the request from being sent and catches it before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Would it send a request or throw an error without sending the request?

Your `POST` request would be sent. However, the same-origin policy prevents that are you are able to read the response. Just like an ordinary form submission, it's a type of *cross-origin write*. Here is an overview [from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy):

> - Cross-origin ***writes*** are typically allowed. Examples are links, redirects and form submissions. Certain rarely used HTTP requests
>     require [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests).
> - Cross-origin ***embedding*** is typically allowed. Examples are listed below.
> - Cross-origin ***reads*** are typically not allowed, but read access is often leaked by embedding. For example you can read the width and
>     height of an embedded image, the actions of an embedded script, or the
>     [availability of an embedded resource](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=629094).

In your scenario, the request would trigger an involuntary action (a bank transfer). This type of attack is called [cross-site request forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) (CSRF). To prevent these, developers have to actively take countermeasures such as implementing [CSRF tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829607/5765873).

> Are there any cases where SOP prevents the request from being sent and
>   catches it before?

**Yes.** For example, you cannot specify methods other than `GET`, `POST` and `HEAD` by default. Other methods need to be explicitly allowed using a technique called [cross-origin resource sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (CORS).  That's why custom methods are sometimes used as a (questionable) alternative to CSRF tokens.

To allow a custom method `FOO` from any origin, the server could reply with these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: FOO
```

Here is how Google Chrome rejects a request with the method `FOO` to `https://www.google.com`:

[image]

You can see that the browser first sends a [preflight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381105/5765873) `OPTIONS` request to check which methods are permitted via CORS. The server then replies with a `405` status indicating that `FOO` is not allowed - and the entire request fails.

Comment: Hi Arminius ,this is perfect , thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: So same origin policy doesn't protect against evil.com sending a POST request that might alter state for the victim on bank.com (even though evil.com won't be able to read the response)?

Comment: @M3RS Exactly! That's why techniques like CSRF tokens are necessary. In that case the bank would check if the POST request contains a specific secret value before altering the state.